Break pages in html_document by chapters as done in bookdown
With this YAML I can have code folding and floating toc, but get one single html:
---
title: "TEST-1"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
    fig_caption: TRUE
    split_chapter
---
# 1. Approach
  
  Ta ta ta

# 2. Area of Study

* 2.2 Geological setting
Ti ti ti

While with this YAML I can break by chapters but cannot have code folding or floating toc.
---
title: "TEST-2"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
---

# 1. Approach
  
  Ta ta ta

# 2. Area of Study

* 2.2 Geological setting
Ti ti ti

Is there any way to have html_document to break into pages
by chapter as done with bookdown, but keep code folding and floating toc?
I have tried the following, but still results into 1 single html page:
---
title: "Your Book Title"
author: "Author Name"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    code_folding: show
    split_by: chapter
documentclass: book
---

# 1. Approach1
  
  Ta ta ta


# 2. Area2

* 2.2 Geological setting
Ti ti ti

